# Can a microphone suddenly stop picking child voices

Tags: microphone, zoom, computer

My parents are complaining that on the last Zoom call (last week was fine) they couldn't hear their son (6 years old) until he used the microphones on a headset.

I run a mic test
Quality Rating: 1334
Microphone Name:    Default - Microphone (1080P Webcam)
Automatic Gain Control: yes
Number of Audio Channels:   1
Echo Cancellation:  yes
Estimated Latency:  0.01
Noise Suppression:  yes
Sample Rate:    48000
Sample Size:    16

https://mictests.com/ gave this result with quiet talking

Despite the mic checking out can it still be a problem to hear him?
I did a sound recording that was good too.

Comment: This sounds more like an issue with the software and probably belongs on a Zoom support page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your parents report they can't hear their son then they can't hear him, whatever some random website says about your microphone.

You could try setting background noise suppression to low in the [Zoom client](https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/360046244692-Suppressing-background-noise-for-videos).

Or you could just let your brother use the headset microphone.

Comment: This week it is fine again. The headset doesn't fit my son.